# Why does my Haskell assertion only happen in IHaskell?

Tags: haskell, assert, assertions

If I define

```
import Control.Exception (assert)
import Data.Char (ord)

f :: String -> String
f s = assert (all (`elem` letters) s) $ (letters!!) <$> (ix <$> s)
    where
        ix ch = (ord ch - ord 'A')
        letters = ['A'..'Z']
```

then if I execute

```
f "AB.CD"
```

in IHaskell, I get

```
:10:7-12: Assertion failed
```

as I would expect. But in all other settings, the assertion seems to be ignored. For example in GHCi (7.10.2) I get

```
ghci>f "AB.CD"
"AB*** Exception: Prelude.!!: negative index
```

and if I put the expression in a program

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ f "AB.CD"
```

I get

```
prgm: Prelude.!!: negative index
"AB
```

Why is my assertion being ignored everywhere but in IHaskell?

---

In GHCi, `:set` gives:

```
options currently set: none.
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
GHCi-specific dynamic flag settings:
other dynamic, non-language, flag settings:
  -fimplicit-import-qualified
warning settings:
```

Comment: The assertion is working fine for me in GHCi 7.10 (which I assume you're using) and 7.6, are you sure about that case? And in the compiled example are you compiling with optimizations? In that case assertions become no-ops

Comment: @jberryman: 7.10.2 (added). Yes, certain. Could I have set something in GHCi that optimizes? I don't have any flags set (that I'm aware of) when I compile.

Comment: Does the output of the `:set` command in GHCi contain `-fignore-asserts`? That would explain GHCi although not standalone GHC... alternatively, GHCi bytecode *never* optimizes, does it contain `-fobject-code`?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Output of `:set` added to question.

Comment: Hm. Another hunch, if you have a `*.o` file for the module/program, try deleting it before trying GHCi again. It may have been compiled with optimizations and then all the other paths pick it up...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: No `*.o` files for the code containing the definition of `f`.

Comment: (I tested on GHCi 7.10.1)

Comment: (I tested on GHC and GHCi 7.10.2)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: I've confirmed that I'm seeing this. Build library, with `f` in it, `import` the library, and run `f` as above: `negative index` (rather than a failed assertion).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Note that I'm using Haskell-Platform 7.10.2-a, if that matters.

Comment: Me too. Cannot reproduce. BTW do you have the `GHC_OPTIONS` environment variable set to anything?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Nope: `env` doesn't list it.

Comment: @jberryman: Indeed, the issue here seems to be simply that `assert` gets turned into a no-op in any compiled code, but if I just load the file (with `:l`) they are not. I'd except that as an answer.