# Is there a way to leave 'assert' enabled in my Hackage package?

Tags: haskell, assert

I have a Haskell package in which I perform some checks using `assert`, but when my package is built on clients' machines, these are generally — [because of, I gather, optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32727418/656912) — turned into no-ops.

Is there a way to persevere `assert` my Hackage package when it is installed on others' machines; or perhaps an alternate approach I can use with the same effect?

Comment: You could always write `verify cond result = if cond then result else error "Failure"` and use that...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Yeah, I guess I just wasn't understanding the `assert` idiom in Haskell (which really isn't that different from some other languages actually): it's a "never should happen" test that's verified during development, but isn't really intended for release — I gather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to, you can specify `-fno-ignore-asserts`. This is probably best done per-file, with a pragma:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-ignore-asserts #-}
```

You really shouldn't leave assertions active in any module that uses them in anything that could potentially be used in a tight loop.